# Django: packaging an app with a ForeignKey to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, packaging

I have an app that I use in many of my projects and want to package it.
A model in the app has ForeignKey and ManyToManyField to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

```
class LogEntry(models.Model):
    authenticated_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,
                                           null=True, related_name='log_entries',
                                           on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    involved_users = models.ManyToManyField(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,
                                            through='LogUsers',
                                            related_name='other_log_entries')
```

migrations of this app in different projects refer to different user models.
Sometimes a custom user model `('user', ... to='registry.RdpUser)` other times the standard `django.contrib.auth.models.User`.

Is it possibile to package the app with a migrations that works for both cases?

What's the best approach for a packaged app with a ForeignKey to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL?

I know a solution would be to use `GenericForeignKey` but I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Even though django generated migration points to the specific model found in settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

('user', ... to='registry.RdpUser')

I have found a migration in django of a migration to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/migrations/0001_initial.py

```
            (
                "user",
                models.ForeignKey(
                    to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                    verbose_name="user",
                ),
            ),
```

So I guess I could have just edited my migration to

```
('user', ... to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

before packaging the app.
I am quite sure it works but haven't tested it as I have used the GenericForeignKey approach.